# How can I use two USB devices with the new USB-C MacBooks?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, mouse, headphones

I recently was provided with the latest MacBook model, for which Apple decided to switch from a number of ports to just one, USB-C port and a headphone jack. The only two accessories that I use on a regular basis, a mouse and a headset, both require a USB port which was not a problem on the old models. One can purchase an adapter to fix this problem, either a USB-C to USB or a USB-C to HDMI+USB+USB-C. Here the problem arises that there is only a single USB-C port, and these adapters only provide one USB port. Is there or will there be a way for me to have both my accessories function? This doesn't seem like an abnormal problem to have, but I can't find very much information on the topic.

Comment: Oh look! I googled "USB-C to USB adapter". http://m.staples.com/V7-V7UC3U-HUB-BLK-1N-USB-C-Male-to-5-in-1/product_IM13N1125?cid=PS:GooglePLAs:IM13N1125&ci_src=17588969&ci_sku=IM13N1125&KPID=IM13N1125&cvosrc=PLA.google-SALES.Computer%20Accessories%20%26%20Peripherals&cvo_crid=191337945062&cvo_campaign=805222455&gclid=CjwKEAjwgZrJBRDS38GH1Kv_vGYSJAD8j4DfDH7DrgnD0_pALpcTrgP-hFAg5DsAoot6dmumDu1kthoC9a_w_wcB and https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01K1QQEF2/

Comment: This is an older question that seems to have been given a bump to the top.  I suspect that there are many solutions available today based on one's budget, such as any of a number of USB-C docks.  If this is no longer a problem then could we have this question marked as closed somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can plug in a USB hub to the available USB port on your USB-C adapter.